# Mouseover effect on all but first row in table

Tags: d3.js

Many thanks to the folks here, particuarly AmeliaBR with my previous problem. Now I've run into a new one, but similar.

I am trying to relate 2 tables to each other so that when you mouse over one it highlights the related rows on the other. It works fine as long as I don't have a row on the one table with only header information, in which case on that table the row selection is one row off. I'd like there to be some way that I can program the .on("mouseover, SelectData) for that line so that I can use the same functions as I use on the other table (and other objects not shown in the example below).

In this example the top table works as expected, the bottom table is one off. There is also a hidden row in the bottom table which will be important but throws everything off.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/g8z5h/7/

Plus, any data on auto-populating these tables from a data object would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break your table into a `<thead>` section versus a `<tbody>` section you can make your selectors only target rows that are part of the main body of the table:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/g8z5h/8/

```
d3.select(".DataDetail").select("tbody tr:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ")")
    .classed("highlight", true);
```

You could also use

```
d3.select(".DataDetail").select("tbody").select("tr:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ")")
    .classed("highlight", true);
```

(It only really makes a difference if you are appending rows dynamically, in which case use the latter version so that your added rows get inserted within the `<tbody>`.)

I'm not sure what you want to do with the hidden row.  Currently it is being selected and the background colour changed the same as any other row, you just can't see it.

If you want to *ignore* the hidden row in your row count, it gets a bit trickier.  The CSS selector can't do the count for you -- [I tried](http://fiddle.jshell.net/g8z5h/9/) using a class-based selector to exclude the hidden row, and then nth-of-type (versus nth-child) to do the count, but the nth-of-type count was still based on all rows, not just the ones that matched the rest of the selector.

Instead, you can use a d3 filter to find the row with the matching index.  However, to make sure that the d3 selection is based on the correct indices (not including the hidden row), you still need to make sure the selector only matches the regular rows.  Since it's the hidden row that has a distinct class value, that means using a `:not(selector)` syntax:

```
d3.select(".DataDetail").selectAll("tbody tr:not(.hidden)")
    .on("mouseover", SelectData)
    .on("mouseleave", SelectNone);

function SelectData(d, i) {
    SelectNone(d,i);

    d3.select(".SelectPanel" + Coord(i))
        .classed("highlight", true);
    d3.select(".DataDetail").selectAll("tbody tr:not(.hidden)")
        .filter(function(d2,j) {return j===i;})
        .classed("highlight", true);
}
```

Note that, in order to be sure that the correct index `i` gets passed to the event handling function, the selector used when adding the event listeners also has to also exclude the hidden rows.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/g8z5h/10/

Comment: Great stuff. This will defiantly help. I'm working on applying now.

I think you misunderstood my hidden field, though. I want to, mostly through the top table, hide data in the bottom table.

Comment: Well, if you're just hiding data rows but want them still to be part of your index count you really don't have to do anything special.  The first example does it that way be default.